# Unable to call Delegate ResponseRecieved.Invoke( ) method in c#

Tags: c#, windows, delegates, invoke

I am using delegate to use invoke method with 2 parameters. but it is giving null reference exception error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Unable to shift control to invoke method in main page. Can anyone tell me why its so..? thanks ..

```
 public override event ResponseRecievedDelegate ResponseRecieved;

    if (reqName == REQUEST_NAME.abc)
        {
            IJsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
            Object resp = parser.GetData(responseString );

            ResponseRecieved.Invoke(reqName, resp); // unable to invoke this method giving null exception ..

        }
```

invoke method implementation is like:

```
   private void OnResponseReceived(REQUEST_NAME requestName, Object response)
    {
        if (requestName == REQUEST_NAME.abc)
        {
           //------------
        }

        else if (requestName == REQUEST_NAME.def)
        { 
           //------------
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you attach to event `ResponseRecieved` anywhere? (`ResponseRecieved += ....`)

Answer (score 1):

you need to check

```
if(ResponseRecieved != null)
```

before calling the event

in general, when using events, before using them we need to check for null. you can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) on the subject

> **Invoking an event** -   Once a class has declared an event, it can treat
>   that event just like a field of the indicated delegate type. The field
>   will either be null, if no client has hooked up a delegate to the
>   event, or else it refers to a delegate that should be called when the
>   event is invoked. Thus, invoking an event is generally done by first
>   checking for null and then calling the event.

if you want the `OnResponseReceived` method to be called you need to register it to the event. you can do it like this:

```
ResponseRecieved += OnResponseReceived;
```

make sure `OnResponseReceived` is in the correct format and you do it before you call the event.

another way will be just call the method...

Comment: yes.. i attach it in button click event like this:
 
private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ICAPI api = new CAPI();
            api.ResponseRecieved += new C.Model.Comm.ResponseRecievedDelegate(OnResponseReceived); 
         }

Comment: i need to invoke & run this method in any case whether ResponseReceived is null or not null.. but it is not transfering control to invoke method implementation & give null exception, how to handle it?

Comment: checking .. but same exception .. :(

Comment: @Marie please share the stack trace of the exception

Comment: In my project, i am using multiple set of classes, to move/get data from different classes etc.. & i just register my delegate to the one MainPage.cs class thats why i was getting error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.. because each time i instanciated an object of a class, ResponseReceived becomes null.. now i added delegate registeration to all classes which are involved in a single button click flow & voila it worked fine! :)

Comment: @Marie glad to here it, even though it means i won't get accepted :) you should put it in an answer so other people will know what solved the problem

Comment: Definitely your answer helped here.. Thanks :) .. but where projects contains multiple classes structure, it needs to register OnResponseReceived method in every class we are using there.